# Eclipse Junit writing tests correctly for getters and setters

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

I need to write Junit tests in Eclipse and I wanted to know if I am on the right track. I have an Allergey.java and TestAllergey.java. I heard you are not supposed to do tests for getters and setters but it is a requirement and I have no choice. I also did a test for the toString method and am curious if I did that correctly. All the tests passed.
Thanks

```
package medical.com.medicalApplication.model;
/**
 * This class represent the Allergy model in the application
 *
 */
public class Allergey {
    private String name;

    public Allergey(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Allergy " + name;
    }   

}

package medicalApplication.model;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import medical.com.medicalApplication.model.Allergey;

public class AllergeyTest {

    private Allergey allergy;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        allergy = new Allergey("Peanut");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetName() {
        String expectedValue = allergy.getName();
        String actualValue = "Peanut";
        assertTrue(expectedValue.equals(actualValue));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetName() {
        String expectedValue = "Peanut";
        allergy.setName(expectedValue);
        String actualValue = allergy.getName();
        assertTrue(expectedValue.equals(actualValue));
    }

    @Test
    public void testToString() {
        assertTrue(allergy.toString().equals("Allergy " + allergy.getName()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the `name` of an existing Allergy instance really allowed to be updated after the instance was created?  If possible, consider using immutable objects which will remove the setter method.  The tests then become more useful, with testing the constructor parameters (only 1 in your example though) were correctly assigned.  See also: lombok or similar alternative

Comment: You are right it should not allowed to be updated. So how would I test the setName method then?

Comment: You would not test it.. because it would not exist

Comment: Mark `name` as final and remove the set method.  Then there would only be a test for `getName()`.

Comment: Also I can understand testinf setters and getters if they have some type of additional logic associated with them.... but when they are just plain gets and sets, I really don't understand the value in testing them

Comment: @RobOhRob - agreed.  And using code generators, such as lombok, removes the need for any explicitly declared methods, including a constructor.  So there are no methods to test, which resolves the useless code coverage metric debate.

Comment: But I still would be testing toString correct? assertTrue(allergy.toString().equals("Allergy " + allergy.getName()));